# Mulitiple Result Set based on certain conditions on a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, resultset

i am printing two result sets based on certain conditions.The first result set contains data whose date is greater than 1 days.The second result set prints the table whose date is greater than 2 days.But in my second table,data of the first table is contained.How do i print the second table without duplicate rows from the first table.(Date is one of the column of the table)

Both the tables are generated by the same query.
I have to write this using java,i cant change my query.
What will i have to do to filter data for duplicates using java code??

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried it with mysql query but i am not getting the desired output.So i searched a little and found out that i need to use Set to avoid duplicates.But i am not aware of how i should proceed?

Comment: I suggest that you add id into a list when its printed. And next time before print you check the list.contains() that element. But this is not very good for a large set of data

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashMap to avoid duplicate keys.

```
    ResultSet rs1 = ... // here goes your first result set
    ResultSet rs2 = ... // here goes your second result set

    // TableRow is a class you can create which contains the fields of your result set
    // including the primary key
    HashMap<String, TableRow> hm = new HashMap<String, TableRow>();

    // First you insert the rows from Result Set 1
    while (rs1.next()) {
        // Obtain primary key
        String pk = rs1.getString("pkey");
        // Obtain fields
        String field1 = rs1.getString("field1");
        String field2 = rs1.getString("field2");
        // ...up to fieldN
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(pk, field1, field2, ...);
        hm.put(pk, TableRow);
    }

    // Then you insert the rows from Result Set 2
    while (rs2.next()) {
        // Obtain primary key
        String pk = rs2.getString("pkey");
        // Obtain fields
        String field1 = rs2.getString("field1");
        String field2 = rs2.getString("field2");
        // ...up to fieldN
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(pk, field1, field2, ...);
        hm.put(pk, TableRow);
    }
```

The HashMap will avoid duplicate keys. If the date is unique for each row, then you can also use the date as the key of the HashMap.

Comment: why will i require the TableRow class with the fields(that i need to display in the resultset) and its getters and setters to be used ?

Comment: Actually the TableRow class is just a wrapper for all the fields in each row, since the ResultSet doesn't have a "getRow()" function which returns the whole row as a single object. You could just define TableRow as a private static class inside your current class with a simple constructor and no getters/setters, and retrieve each field like tr.field1, tr.field2, etc. Another solution is to store the list of fields in a single string separated by commas and then just do a string.split(",") to get the list of field values.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.I am printing the result set on a jsp directly.i generated the TableRow class seperately with getters and setters of the fields.I used on the jsp with HashMap ,but what if i am using the same result set and looping according to the conditions

Comment: i tried using the above code,but still am getting the duplicated rows in the second resultset.Plz help me???in the second result set i shouldnt get duplicates.

Comment: I didn't really understand your question about looping according to the conditions, but once both results sets have been added to the HashMap, you can traverse it by obtaining the collection of values (TableRow instances) using the values() method. For example:
`for (TableRow tr : hm.values()) {`
`    // manipulate table rows`
`}`
If you are indeed using a unique key (the first argument of the hm.put() method) then there shouldn't be any duplicate rows in the HashMap instance. You can also try using your date column as the HashMap key, as long as it is a unique timestamp.

Comment: now the method has been changes.I am adding the resultset data to an arraylist and then looping it according to the conditions.